# Which one is better to user between Parse, Firebase and AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, firebase, amazon-cognito

I am willing to use synchronisation service for my application. But I want to choose the best one. I want to know which one is better among all these. My application will run on Android , IOS , Windows and Web.

I am going with Firebase because I tested it. It is giving me fast results and it is also allowing me to work offline. Is it better or I will go with Parse or AWS Cognito?

I Also have an option of Google Cloud. Does Google Cloud provides service like Firebase? And are realtime updates possible with Parse as like Firebase?

Comment: Opinion based question will give you opinion based answers O.O

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Codeek has a good point that this question is opinion based, so take my answer with a grain of salt.

I have experience with both Parse and Firebase, but not with Cognito. 
In my experience, Parse is better when working with large relationship-based databases. (I.E. databases where multiple classes of objects are pointing to each other and interact.) In this system, it is easy to store a lot of data very succinctly, but working with this data is done via snapshots. This means that you can take a snapshot of the data, edit it, and then refresh the server with the updated snapshot. This is perfect for things like my delivery application where only one user is updating the orders on our server at any one time.

Firebase implements a model-observer scheme, and so it is much better for applications that are highly interactive. For instance, I have used Firebase for creating a real-time game of hot potato. The advantage here is that changes to the data on the server are automatically pushed out to all devices that have registered as listeners (functionality not available on Parse from my experience). This keeps all users on the same page all the time. The downside is that the database is structured in a hierarchal manner and doesn't have defined "objects". Rather, it is structured via key/value pairs where parent keys cannot have an associated value. To illustrate this, a sample structure for storing a game on my database went something like this:

```
-Games  
--1  
---Users  
----1 = "example@gmail.com"  
----2 = "example2@gmail.com"  
---PotatoHolder = 1  
---TimeRemaining = 30  
---Loser = -1
```

Cognito I am not familiar with, so I'll allow someone else to explain how that database system is designed.

> In summary, codeek is correct that this is an opinion-based question, but for two of your options a good rule of thumb from my experience is that Parse is fantastic for large relationship databases in conjunction with single-user applications (i.e. single-player or turn based games). Firebase is more suited to hierarchal data systems in conjunction with real-time multiplayer applications.

I hope this helps! If you could post a little more about what kind of application you are trying to build then perhaps I, or someone else, could provide a little more guidance.

**Expanded Answer:** Although this question has been marked as off topic, to answer Nidhi's follow-up question if there is a way to use Parse as a model-observer scheme: *Not easily*. Using a timer is the simplest option. The other option is to use push notifications. **This would require getting permission from you user**. You can set the Cloud Code on Parse to automatically send push notifications all relevant users and then intercept them within your client so that they are "silent". In other words, when they arrive, you can have your client respond by updating your game without showing a ribbon or notification like normal push notifications. I have not done this myself, as I prefer using Firebase for that kind of application, but I believe that it is possible.
*Source:* [PFQueryTableView Auto Refresh When New Data Updated or Refresh Every Minute Using Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751714/pfquerytableview-auto-refresh-when-new-data-updated-or-refresh-every-minute-usin)
Keith's answer is similar to Nidhi's reference to refreshing PFObjects via a Timer, Handsomeguy's comment refers to the possibility of "silent" push notifications.

Comment: Is it possible to get realtime data from parse at run time without refresh.

Comment: Nidhi, please refer to the Expanded Answer section of my post for an answer to your follow-up question.

Comment: Facebook is shutting down the Parse Web Services from Jan 2017, plz do through the following link.  http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: what is the better option now..?? Firebase..??

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Irshad. What Piyush pointed out is that Facebook is shutting down the Parse servers, and so the **online service will no longer be offered as of ~1 year of this comment**. While I still don't have experience with Cognito, this leave Firebase as the only other "out-of-the-box" service that I am comfortable with recommending due to my familiarity with it. However, Parse has open sourced its stack and so it can be [duplicated using a hosting service like AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/resources-for-migrating-parse-applications-to-aws/).